# Secure url with ADMIN role Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to make all requests with /secure path require ADMIN role.
What I have is a controller:

```
@Controller("/secure")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping("/allPosts")
    public String allPosts(Model model){
        //some logic
        return "admin/allPosts";
    }
}
```

Where allPosts is a HTML/Thymeleaf page in src/main/resources/templates/admin.
Here is my config piece:

```
.antMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

When I access localhost:8080/secure/allPosts it shows 404 as expected, but I can also access localhost8080/allPosts and this is wrong. How is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

`@Controller("/secure")` - this is your error. Annotation value is actually bean name, not request mapping. And 404 is not expected - you should expect 403. Try the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/secure")
public class AdminController
```